# How to go from Linux to Windows?

Tags: boot, windows, hard-disk

Installing any **Linux** distro while having **Windows 10** installed is pretty easy and straight forward, but my problem is I installed pop os on my computer, now I need to completely wipe the **Linux** distro from my computer and replace it with **Windows 10**. I created a partition with the NTFS format (using the **Pop_os!** bootable usb) but whenever I try to install **Windows 10** (using another bootable usb) Im having an error which is the hard drive are not showing on the **Windows 10** installation process, even when using the disk part cmd command the hard drive is not displaying.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This might help: https://itsfoss.com/install-windows-after-ubuntu-dual-boot/

Answer (score 0):

You could try to install [GParted](https://gparted.org/) onto an USB-stick and boot into it. Once you're in, you click on `Device` > `Create partition table` > select which partition table you'd like (you could use MBR, but I'd recommend GPT) > confirm. Then, when you're back on the "main menu", you select the disk(s) you want to format, and partition them to `NTFS`. Wait for it to finish, reboot the PC into the Windows USB, and the disks *should* now be visible.